# Is there a Quickly command to completely remove a project

Tags: application-development, quickly

I am trying out application development with Quickly but I have a couple of projects that I have come to nothing and I want to completely remove them.

Is there a command to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I do not now if my approach is the best practice!

But if you have performed a quickly install in the directory beforehand!

Then i would cd to the directory and run : quickly uninstall 
Then  cd ..   and do rm -rf  . 
This approach works for me! ;)

Comment: There is no quickly uninstall command so I used apt-get purge quickly the removed to project folders as suggested.  The reinstalled quickly.

Comment: Oh sorry, the uninstall command is for when you working with ubuntu-lenses ;) - then just remove the folder! ;)
You do not have to apt-get remove --purge quickly each time .

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all project files are stored in one folder.
The following command wil do the trick

```
# rm -rv /path/to/project/folder
```